# Making wxPython GUI launch on a different screen from Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, wxpython

I currently have a dual-monitor setup with Eclipse on monitor 2. When I run the code that launches the wxPython GUI, I would like for this GUI to appear on monitor 1. Currently, the GUI consistently appears on monitor 2, covering Eclipse, and I have to drag it to monitor 1 every time. Is there a solution to this problem -- either a configuration change I can make in Eclipse or some addition I can make to the GUI code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kludge #2: If I run the code from Eclipse on screen 2 then click someplace on screen 1 before the GUI appears, the GUI will appear on screen 1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think I remember reading something about windows sticking to the same monitor as the process that spawned them. Therefore, it might be a worthwhile experiment to edit your code in eclipse (on monitor 2) and have a command prompt window open on monitor 1 from which you can run the python code. Since it will be command prompt window that is spawning the GUI, it should appear on monitor 1 as you would like.

This is just a hacky solution (that too, only if I remember correctly). As for an option in eclipse, I have no idea about that. I only posted a thought because nobody has replied yet.

You might also want to try posting on [superUser](https://superuser.com/), perhaps someone there can help.

Answer (score 0):

The best kludge I found was the Kubuntu global shortcut "Ctrl-Shift-Space". This moves a window to the other screen, mitigating the hassle of dragging with the mouse.